# Every open subset is affine

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

I have the following question: given a ring $R$, what conditions should verify $R$, such that  every open subset of $\text{Spec}(R)$ is affine?

Comment: Do you have a reason to think this has a simple answer?

Comment: No, that´s the reason why I´m asking.

Comment: Here are some obstructions : if $R$ has dimension at least two and is normal, then for any (smooth) point $p$, $\text{Spec}(R) \backslash \{p\}$ is not affine.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Ha! You beat me by two minutes (in my defense, I gave some details...)

Comment: @Stephen : Sure, same did happens to me lot of time, and it's more easy to write a comment.

Comment: It seems plausible to me that it is sufficient for $\operatorname{Spec} R$ to be Noetherian and at most 1-dimensional.  It also seems plausible that these conditions might be necessary if $R$ is Noetherian.  (They aren't if $R$ is not Noetherian, since you could have a 2-dimensional valuation ring, for instance.)  The condition that $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is Noetherian definitely is necessary, since otherwise it will have an open subset that is not even quasicompact.

Comment: Sorry, when I said "$\operatorname{Spec} R$ is Noetherian" I meant it is a Noetherian topological space, not a Noetherian scheme.

Comment: @Eric: since you clarified your meaning I have erased my previous comment.

Answer (score 5):

Motivation: consider the ring $R=\mathbf{C}[x,y]$ of polynomial functions on $\mathbf{C}^2$. The union of the two principal open subschemes with coordinate rings $R[x^{-1}]$ and $R[y^{-1}]$ is not affine by Hartog's theorem: the ring of functions on it is $\mathbf{C}[x,y]$. Geometrically, at the level of closed points this open subscheme is the punctured plane $\mathbf{C}^2 \setminus \{(0,0) \}$.

Something similar happens at least whenever your ring $R$ is Noetherian, normal, and of Krull dimension at least $2$: fixing a maximal ideal $m$ of $R$ that is not generated by one element we have a non-affine open subset
$$\bigcup_{f \in m} \mathrm{Spec}(R[f^{-1}])=\mathrm{Spec}(R) \setminus \{ m \}.$$ This subset is not affine because, by the algebraic version of Hartog's lemma (see e.g. Ravi Vakil's book), the space of sections of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}(R)}$ over it is just $R$.

Comment: I forgot to say noetherian. Nice answer ! (+1)

Comment: Using generic smoothness, one should be able to use this partial answer to show that for a finite type $k$-algebra, being at most one-dimensional is necessary.